# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'invest_id' cannot be null

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-6

all

Please help with the above error.

I am trying to post data to the database.

This is the table below :

```
public function up() {
        Schema::create('investment', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->decimal('amount');
            $table->integer(**'invest_id')->unsigned()**;
            $table->integer('reference_id')->unsigned();`
```

This is the code on the controller

```
public function confirm(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [

            'amount' => 'required|numeric',
            'plan_id' => 'required|numeric',

        ]);

        $interest = new Interest();
        $interest->invest_id = $request->invest_id;
        $interest->user_id = $user->id;
        $interest->save();
```

Comment: So `$request->invest_id` is empty. Is `invest_id` allowed to be empty?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve this is set `'strict' => false,` in your `config/database.php` file. The other way is to add `$table->integer('invest_id')->unsigned()->nullable();` to inform the database the value can be null. The default `'strict' => true,` option brought me into some issues in the past, as it was introduced in Laravel 5.2.

If you run a brand new application, you could go for the strict option but you'll have to set up your database accordingly.

Comment: I've not used laravel but it can change DB constraints?

Comment: Yes indeed, it is a MySQL option as explained here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-strict It is valuable, and set to true in a new laravel installation. but keep in mind you'll have to respect the strict option throughout your application. I've found this somewhat annoying, especially with updates. A counter for instance, where a article visit is added +1, you'll need to update every field of the database input, not only the counter value. This is why I opted to set strict to false.